# How do I find a Profile Dir of a Windows User (not the current user) using Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

Question could be simple enough I was trying with this code:

```
var
 lpProfileDir            : tChar;
 lpProfileSize           : Cardinal;
 token                   : tHandle;
 GuestDir,GuestUser      : String;

begin
 GuestUser:=RadioGroup1.Items[RadioGroup1.ItemIndex];
 if LogonUser(PChar(GuestUser), nil, nil, LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token) then
  begin
    SetLength(GuestDir, MAX_PATH);
    ZeroMemory(@GuestDir[1], MAX_PATH);
    lpProfileSize:=MAX_PATH;
    if GetUserProfileDirectoryA(token, PChar(GuestDir), lpProfileSize) then
     begin
       ShowMessage(GuestDir);
    ...
```

Now, this returns the current users Profile Directory. Bare in mind I would like to use this app under Windows XP/Vista/7/8.

Comment: What user do you mean when saying "Windows User" ? Do you mean you need profile folder of specific user (for example from variable "GuestUser" in your code) ?

Comment: Pointless ZeroMemory. Strings and dyn arrays are zero initialised. And anyway, the function you call assigns the buffer. It overwrites your initialisation.

Comment: Andrei: GuestUser in the test case is 'Guest
David: I see, I found this code on the web thought thats the way to go.

Comment: Andrei: In short, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`GetUserProfileDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of `SHGetFolderPath`.

Sample (you need bindings for GetUserProfileDirectory in UserEnv.dll):

```
if LogonUser(PChar(GuestUser), 0, 0, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, token) then 
begin
  SetLength(GuestDir, MAX_PATH);
  ZeroMemory(@GuestDir[1], MAX_PATH);
  if Succeeded(GetUserProfileDirectoryA(token, PChar(GuestDir), MAX_PATH)) then 
    ShowMessage(GuestDir); 
end;
```

Comment: Could you provide a simple example? I can't seem to get it work... Teşekkürler!

Comment: @modzsi you need bindings for UserEnv.dll, pretty much like http://read.pudn.com/downloads62/ebook/218392/UserEnv.pas__.htm

Comment: I gave up for today... Maybe tommorow, have another go at it. for now i just did this:

`if SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(0,CSIDL_PERSONAL,0,SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,@path[0])) then
    GuestDir := StringReplace(path,GetUserNameFromWindows,GuestUser,[rfReplaceAll])`

Comment: LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE instead of LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE and it works just fine for all accounts... Teşekkürler!

Comment: In Windows 10, with a NULL password, LogonUser always fails with error ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE.